# ChartJS match X-Y axis from PHP array

Tags: php, charts, chart.js

Im using [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/) to build a time/line graph. Im having a hard time matching my **X axis** (Days per month) and **Y axis** (Entries per month)

[image]

I want this data array to be displayed on my chart, using **X-axis(Days per month)** and `array['date']` as its common reference.

```
[0] => Array ( 
        [count] => 2 
        [date] => 2017-11-07 ) 

[1] => Array ( 
        [count] => 3 
        [date] => 2017-11-08 )

[2] => Array ( 
        [count] => 6 
        [date] => 2017-11-09 ) 

[3] => Array ( 
        [count] => 2 
        [date] => 2017-11-10 ) 
)
```

Here is my code, omitted some lines

```
var data = {
    labels : [<?php echo "'".$daysofthemonth."'"; ?>], //print days of month
    datasets :
           [
            {
                ....
                data : [{
                    x: array['date'] here, //this should match the x-axis
                    y: array['count'] here}],
                ...
            },
          ]
```

if the some dates in the array are not existing, it should equate `count` to **0**

**Expectation**

[image]